# How do I count wildcard characters using Excel COUNTIF?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, countif

How do I count the number of cells that contain the string "A*" - without treating the star as a wildcard character?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoted directly from Excel help documents:
"If you want to find an actual question mark or asterisk, type a tilde (~) before the character."

COUNTIF(A1:A4,"A~*")